# Highlighting the higher value of two rows using conditional formatting in excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have an excel array in which I have two rows with percentages like so:
[image]

How can I highlight which cell in each column is higher (e.g 27.5% or 30%) using conditional formatting?

Comment: Create a CF rule **for each column** and apply to highlight the highest value

Comment: Use max(cell 1,cell 2) to control the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by selecting the column, then go to home>conditional formatting>new rule>Format only top or bottom ranked values> and then select top and 1.  choose a custom format for your higher value and then select 'ok'.

Answer (score 0):

Since conditional formatting is volatile, it won't matter to add some volatile functions either. Therefor try utilize `OFFSET()`:

[image]

- Select `B2:D3`;
- Add a custom rule through formula;
- Use something like: `=B2>=OFFSET(B2,CHOOSE(ROW()-1,1,-1),0)`.